# Commutative Convolution. Problem 26 Royden 2 ed.

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, convolution

Let $f$ and $g$ be functions in $L^1(—\infty,\infty)$, and define $f\ast g$ to be the
function $h$ defined by $h(y) = \int f(y — x)g(x) dx$.

Why $f\ast g=g\ast f$?

I have this:
If $y-x=z$ then $\int f(y-x)g(x)dx=\int f(z)g(y-z)(-dz)=-g\ast f$

Comment: See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/647179/commutativity-of-convolutions), or perhaps [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4445/proving-commutativity-of-convolution-f-ast-gx-g-ast-fx)?

Comment: when you changed variables, you didn't change the interval of integration. $\infty -> - \infty$ and vice versa

Comment: Okay, but what happens to the limits of integration at the same time?

Answer (score 3):

The indefinite integral is not a value by a function (the anti-derivative of the integrand).  Convolution is defined with a definite integral as follows:
$$ (f\ast g)(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(y-x) g(x) \, dx. $$

Now let's do the substitution where $z=y-x$.  Then
$$ (f\ast g)(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f(z) \, g(y-z) \, (-dz). $$
Bringing out the negative sign and reversing the limits of integration yields
$$ (f\ast g)(y) = \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} g(y-z) \, f(z) \, dz = (g\ast f)(y). $$

Comment: The substitution of variable is valid in Lebesgue integral?

Comment: @eraldcoil The substitution is valid as a Riemann integral.  Doesn't that make it automatically valid as a Lebesgue integral?  I'm not sure.